# Deploy Application on another machine

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config

I developed a simple winforms app, with a service-based DB  with it.

When running the app on my machine it works fine. But after publishing the app and place it on the other machine it installs and runs normally but when it comes to connecting to the DB it throws an error.

> "An attempt to attach auto-named database for file"

**Using the below connection string:**

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="MyConString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\myDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
```

**Calling the connection as:**

```
static string constr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConString"].ConnectionString;
        static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constr);
```

having SQL server installed on the targeted machine...

am i missing something ?

Comment: I doubt that's the actual error message you receive ("AN attempt"?). Does the other machine have the same `|DataDirectory|`, and is there a file named `myDB.mdf` located in that folder?

Comment: @KenWhite Yes the error as stated and yes im including the db when publishing.. But im not getting the |DataDirectory| part how can i make it variable.. Cz i think thts where its stopping..app not finding the db path..

Comment: MS actually released something that says "*AN* attempt"? Their QC has gotten pretty poor; you probably should file a bug report for the sloppiness. (If the typo doesn't exist, it's not the actual message you received, (my point).) The DataDirectory would be the location where you're installing the copy of the DB, and you can state that in the connection string or in your application's configuration file. Clearly, if you try to open `C:\MyAppDir\MyDB.MDF`, then the `MyDB.MDF` file has to be in `C:\MyAppDir` on the destination machine, and if it's not you have to open it from the proper folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below link is a step by step tutorial to deploy an application, through creating a setup:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12548/Visual-Studio-Windows-Application-Setup-Project

Answer (score 1):

Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS
The "." here means Sql server database on your local machine.
If you deploy this application to another machine, 
you have to change "." to your local machine IP address(assume they are in same local network).

Answer (score 1):

You should change datasource name where database exist "." means it exists on local machine. If you don't want to change datasource name then you should put database on same system.